# Formalising definite description using identity in Predicate Logic

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

> "Stockholm is the largest city in Sweden"

I am to provide my own key. The only "help" I've received is that I am not allowed to use designators for the definite description. I should use a two-place predicate "Lxy: x is larger than y". And consider then that Stockholm is the largest city if there is no larger city.

My thought was using this key:

> a: Stockholm
>
> b: Sweden
>
> Lxy: x is larger than y
>
> Cxy: x is a city in y

Then I came up with this translation:

$$Cab \space\ \wedge \forall x((\neg x=a \wedge Cxb) \rightarrow   \neg Lxa)$$

"Stocholm is a city in Sweden and for all things if it is not identical to Stockholm and a city in Sweden, then it is not larger than Stockholm", I think.

What are your thoughts?
Is it perhaps a bit redundant to use a two-place predicate for x is a city in Sweden? would it be better to just have:

> Cx: x is a city in Sweden    ?
> and then:
> $$ Ca \space\ \wedge \forall x((\neg x=a \wedge Cx) \rightarrow   \neg Lxa)  $$

Is both permissible?

Thank you!

Comment: **Forget this if it confuses you**: It looks like you've stumbled upon many-sorted predicate calculus (if you let $x$ and $y$ in $Cxy$ range over different domains, writing, say, $Cx^{\sigma}y^{\tau}$ for sorts $\sigma$ and $\tau$, etc.; countries aren't cities).

Comment: I get your point, but I've never heard of it before. Do you think it would be better to have just "Cx: x is a city in Sweden", then; or does the same thing apply there?

Comment: It's up to you, really. Sorts can complicate things unnecessarily (but they're helpful for, say, vector spaces). It's all down to what $x$ and $y$ can be. The context is clear enough here for it not to be an issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I like your first translation, in terms of using $Cxy$ to denote "x is a city in y", though either should work.

Saying that "no city in Sweden is larger than Stockholm" is not quite the same thing as saying "Stockholm is ***the*** largest city in Sweden". The first allows for the existence of a city *just as large* but *not larger than*, Stockholm. However, we want to say "Stockholm is *larger than* all other cities in Sweden, that is, we want to say "Stockholm is *the* [one and only] largest city in Sweden."

So I would use your first translation key and write:

$$Cab \space\ \wedge \forall x\,\Big((Cxb \land \neg (x=a)) \rightarrow  Lax\Big)$$

This modification now translates as "Stockholm is a city in Sweden and for all things $x$, if $x$ is a city in Sweden and $x$ is not identical to Stockholm, then Stockholm is larger than $x$".

Comment: Hm. You are probably right. Thanks! I also considered something similar in the beginning, but I was a bit confused by the "hints": "consider that Stockholm is the largest city if there is no larger city", because that made me think I should use negation, but I've probably misunderstood it, hehe. Thanks again!

Comment: If you were *given* the hint to "consider that Stockholm is the largest city if there is no city larger than Stockholm," then your translation says just that. I just dispute the equivalence of "Stockholm is **the** largest city in Sweden" with "No other city in Sweden is larger than Stockhholm." If the statement to be translated were "Stockholm is **a** (one among others) largest city in Sweden". But if that hint was given in the assignment itself, or in the text, then I'd include both translations, with an explanation as to how each translates.

Comment: Good idea! You are probably also correct, I think. My lecturer has used the same exercises with small variations for a lot of years now, so it is not rare that the "hints" provided sometimes seems a bit strange or not accurate, because he has forgotten that he has changed them in important ways. But, I'll probably include both and explain, thank you!

Comment: You're welcome, tom!

Comment: @amWhy: Nice feedback +1

Answer (score 2):

I think that $Cx$ meaning "$x$ is a city in Sweden" is simpler, as it means that you can think of all variables ranging over only and exactly cities, instead of cities-or-possibly-countries that you distinguish by context.

Now, your and amWhy's answers are completely reasonable, but just for fun, here are some other possible approaches:

\[Ca \wedge \forall x. [Cx \implies (x = a \vee Lax)]\]

"Stockholm is in Sweden, and every city in Sweden is either Stockholm or smaller than it".

\[Ca \wedge \forall x. [(Cx \wedge \neg Lax) \implies a = x]\]

"Stockholm is in Sweden, and if a city is in Sweden and Stockholm is not bigger than it, then it must be because it IS Stockholm".

My personal favourite:

\[Ca \wedge \forall x. [Lxa \implies \neg Cx]\]

"Stockholm is in Sweden, and if a city is larger than Stockholm, it is not in Sweden".

Comment: Hello! I have now received feedback on the exercises, and I lost marks because I used a one-place prediacte (Cx) instead of a two-place (Cxy) ... Apparently one should always leave as many gaps as possible ... What are your thoughts? :)

Comment: I think that's silly and confers no real advantage, but I'm no authority on the matter.